# How I get bounds UIImageView Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

I have some trouble here with this...

How I convert this piece of code to Swift:

```
imageView.layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:yourImageView.bounds].CGPath;
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here you go:

```
imageView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect:yourImageView.bounds).CGPath
```

Comment: For general rules about how to convert Objective-C initializer calls into Swift, see "Initialization" in [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/InteractingWithObjective-CAPIs.html).